# Roots of a cubic equation with coefficients based on unknown values $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cubics

I want to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix:
$$
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & b \\
a & 0 & c \\
b & c & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$

So, I found the characteristic equation, $\lambda^3-(a^2+b^2+c^2) \lambda - 2abc = 0$.
But I am unable to find the roots by observation. Is there a way I can find the roots of the equation?

If you are interested, my goal is to find distinct values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that the matrix $M$ has integer eigenvalues. Also, simple "$a = -b$" type trivial solutions are not allowed.

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: Are $a, b, c$ supposed to be integers?

Comment: This is not a kind of equation in which you can see the roots by some kind of observation. If I am not mistaken, it was this kind of equation that lead to Cardano's Formula for the cubic. That's not a very "friendly" formula....Remember, one can have one real and 2 complex eigenvalues as wel...

Comment: @imranfat I think OP wants us to find a way of defining $a,b,c$ so that the eigenvalues turn out "nice". I think we need a little more information though ..

Comment: This is a basic level linear algebra class I am taking, I wouldn't expect the values to be too complicated. Also, @imranfat the values are real as the matrix M is symmetric.

Comment: @taninamdar I want to choose different values for a,b and c such that the eigen values are integers.

Answer (score 3):

Set $a = 0$, then we have

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 & c \\ b & c & 0}. $$

The eigenvalues are defined by $ -\lambda(\lambda^2 - c^2) + b^2\lambda = 0 $, so we have $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}$.

Choose Pythagorean triple values such as $b = 3$ and $c = 4$.

Then we have $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = \pm5$.

Does this answer your question?

Note that [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+-+%28a%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%2B+c%5E2%29x+-2abc+%3D+0) is the kind of solution you get if you do not reduce the domain of the problem.

**EDIT:**

Also, you might also be interested in [Vieta's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas) for cubic polynomials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I am not sure, as my professor said "He doesn't want merely solutions like, a=-b" I have to verify.

Comment: @Naren If this is for a basic linear algebra course, there is either a typo or you are missing a part of the question I think. Good luck though!

Comment: My professor gave this hint: "Look for cases where largest eigenvalue is relatively small" which doesn't make any sense to me. Also I am directly quoting from the notes he puts on his website so I don't think I am missing anything here.

Comment: It actually looks like you can get some useful information from Vieta's formulas. +1

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It seem to relate the signed sum of sub-products of the roots with coefficients. This information is already known from the construction of characteristic equation from the matrix. I might be missing something, I will try to go through it again.

Comment: I would love to see a generalization for all integer solutions, but I think that's past my current capability. I've seen crazier things before on stackexchange though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sum of the eigenvalues is 0. If all eigenvalues are integers, then all coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are integers. Set $d=a^2+b^2+c^2$, an integer.

Suppose $n$ is an integer eigenvalue. Dividing $\lambda-n$ into the char poly gives $$ \lambda^2+n\lambda+(n^2-d).$$
This has roots $$\frac{-n\pm \sqrt{4d-3n^2}}{2}.$$
These are integers precisely when $\sqrt{4d-3n^2}=2k+n$ for some integer $k$. In which case the eigenvalues are $k,k-n,n$. These sum to zero precisely when $k=0$. Equivalently, $d=n^2$.

Whence we have all integer eigenvalues if and only if $a^2+b^2+c^2=n^2$ is a perfect square, in which case the eigenvalues are $0,\pm n$.

You then find that $2abc=0$ holds, whence one of $a,b, c$ is zero. The  remaining two solve a (signed) right triangle with hypotenuse $n$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Result from MATLAB, using symbolic manipulation on MuPad (Source: Guodong Xie).